# Fehler (error) 6 - the requested item could not be loaded

Tags: android, rest, http, servlets, mime-types

Currently I'm developing android application that needs to connect itself to REST API. It is crucial for my app to access API whenever connection is possible (mobile data/wifi).

But when testing my app something extremely weird happened. Application works as expected almost all the time, but when on VipMobile operator (Austria telekom group) I cannot connect to API.

At first I didn't get it, error was too unreadable. It says

```
j u fehler6 the requested item could not be loaded & wrong mime type
```

There are a lot of unprintable chars in that message too. When i figured out that it is operator fault i tried to copy link to my API and got this. [image: Screenshot 1]

What could that possibly be? Can anyone point me in any direction, I cannot publish application as long as there are those ridickulous errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the user is on 3g connection. Some mobile operators intercept clients request and if the Content-Type is not good, or not defined they display page like this. This happens also to vipmobile operator in Serbia.

Try to add right content-type to response headers on your server side.

Try to put for example Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8 to headers